# kivy: firing multiple functions on 1 button click

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have this code and it works, but I'm sure it's not the way to go properly. In my .kv a button fires two functions in my main.py.

```
    Button:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_release: root.on_our_btn_release(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.get_items(text_input.text)
```

Next step in my awesome project will be adding a lot more functions that will have to go off when the same button is clicked. This will result in a rather long list like:

```
    Button:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_release: root.on_our_btn_release(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.get_items(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.another_function(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.andanotherone(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.herewegoagain(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.this_is_getting_boring(text_input.text)
    on_release: root.think_you_got_the_picture(text_input.text)
```

This looks to me as very ugly code, but I didn't find a pretty way to do this yet.

Anyone? Thanks in advance!

;-) Erik

Answer (score 3):

You could structure this in a number of different ways, and the best option is mostly up to you.

One option if you don't want too many functions in kv is to call a single root.do_everything(), and put all the other calls in that on the python side.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already guessed (and found on Google) that there are numerous ways to fix this, but I like to learn what  would be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a slightly more elegant solution would be to indent and list the different callbacks.

```
on_release:
    first()
    second()
```

Another possible but ugly solution for this can be to separate the functions with a semicolon.

```
on_release: first(); second()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of "on_press" and "on_release". Assign one method/function to "on_press" and the other to "on_release"

Comment: Could you share a code example on how to do it?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I believe they mean binding one function to `on_press` (ex. `on_press: first()`) and another one to `on_release` (ex. `on_release: second()`)

Comment: yes I definitely meant what @Pokechu48 just stated